# Hide FaceSets Visivility

Tags: sculpting

Is there a way to hide the colours of the facesets we have created without hiding the geometry that belong to them?

A sort of a.... Shift +F in Zbrush Equivalent. A toggle to hide or show the mesh with the facesets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind.
Viewport overlays > sculpt > face sets slider / toggle.

Found it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 4.0 moved to *Sculpt > Face Sets* slider, toggle directly to the right.
[image]